# jQuery selector for elements wrapped inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have trouble getting values of all checkboxes which are selected. 
These checkboxes are inside list which is wrapped inside a div. Like below:

```
<div id="accDC">
     <ul id="chkDC">
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">
               <label class="checkbox">
                 <input id="9" type="checkbox" value="9">  Brazil </input>
               </label>
              </a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">
               <label class="checkbox">
                 <input id="14" type="checkbox" value="14">  Germany </input>
               </label>
              </a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

When I try to do this:

```
$('#chkDC input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
                          getAllValue()
                      });
```

getAllValue returns me string which is actually comma separated values:

```
function getAllValue() {
                 var sThisVal = '';
                 $('#chkDC input:checkbox').each(function () {
                     sThisVal = sThisVal + (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "") + ',';
                 });
                 alert(sThisVal);
             }
```

Currently this alert is like:  ,9,,,,,14,,18 which is obvious because getAllValue is called on each checkbox selection change event.

How can I call it only for < li > elements which have class = '.active' ?

Below does not seems to work, I tried:

```
$('#accDC > li.active > input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
                 alert('new selector');
                 getAllValue()
             });
```

ADDITIONAL INFO: This list of checkboxes have lots of items which I am building dynamically.

Comment: It doesn't work because none of the `li.active` elements are, or can be, direct children of the `#accDC` element. Incidentally it's invalid to nest an interactive element (`input`) within another interactive element (`a`).

Comment: Okay, But it does'nt work for #chkDC either!

Comment: Because the inputs arent direct decendants of li, it goes `#accDC > #chkDC > li > a > label > input` dont use the direct decendant operator if you dont wont to specify each direct decendant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code by binding click on `li.active`; use **[`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** pseudo selector,

```
$('#chkDC li.active input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
    getAllValue()
});

function getAllValue() {
    var sThisVal = $('#chkDC :checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    alert(sThisVal);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44U7W/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try,

The event binding should be like this,

```
$('#chkDC li.active :checkbox').on('change', getAllValue);
```

And the getAllValue function should be,

```
function getAllValue() {
  var values = $('#chkDC li.active :checkbox:checked').map(function () {
      return this.value; 
  }).get().join(); //9,12, ... return values of checked check boxes 
}
```

Comment: Yes, better way to wire event that way :)

Answer (score 1):

The proper selector for checkboxes is:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

And if you want the checked ones:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

As **#accDc** has no direct child **li** and also **li** don't have **checkbox** direct child, you need to apply following selector:

Change it to this:

```
$('#accDC li.active input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
                 alert('new selector');
                 getAllValue()
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery "**on**" function has wrong syntax in following code :

```
$('#accDC > li.active > input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
                 alert('new selector');
                 getAllValue()
             });
```

Syntax should be

**.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )**

Read on event documentation for reference.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Try the below code.

```
$('#chkDC > li.active').on('change','input[type=checkbox]', function () {
                 alert('new selector');
                 getAllValue()
             });
```